# Implementar setScrollListener en un RecylerVview

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo una vista que contiene un botón flotante en la parte inferior derecha, y en un recyclerView un listado de opciones (imágenes de productos). Deseo que cuando el usuario haga scroll-down en la lista de productos, el botón flotante se oculte y tan pronto haga scroll-up el botón flotante aparezca.

La estructura del xml en el layout es...

```
**<cordinatorlayout>**
      <constraintlayout>
         <recyclerview>
      </constraintlayout>
**</constraintlayout>**
  <floatingactionbutton>
</cordinatorlayout>
```

el cordinatorlayout contiene un constraintlayout, y el botón flotante esta al mismo nivel del cordinatorlayout

Es mi primera vez con Android y Kotlin, alguien me puede dar una luz, he buscado en muchas partes pero casi todo es java y poco claro (pienso)

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado. Si no sabes como empezar lee la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#react-to-scroll-position)

Comment: Buena tarde, mas de lo comentado no he podido implementar nada, por que no se por donde empezar,  he buscado mucho, inicialmente aqui (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener) pero no es que diga mucho! Voy a mirar tu enlace, que de antemano agradezco mucho, mil gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas usando [Material Component](https://material.io/components?platform=android) y el boton flotante esta dentro de un coordinator layout, coloca `layout_behavior com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior` como propiedad del boton

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />
```

con kotlin

```
 findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview).addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if (dy > 0 ||dy<0 && fab.isShown()){
                    fab.hide()
                }
            }

            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    fab.show();
                }
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        })
```